# I want to emboss paper at mass quantity

Tags: print-design, diecut

I found this manual embossing machine: [Cuttlebug](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0047Z4GOU)

However, manually embossing would take too long for my purposes. Can anyone recommend an automatic machine?

Answer (score 1):

As with most things, it comes down to costs.

You can hire a print provider to emboss for you. They have big automated machines to emboss thousands of sheets quickly.

If you don't want to pay for that, then you are limited in your ability to improve upon the time necessary for manual embossing.

Comment: The set-up for the die can be expensive enough for small runs, but the per-sheet cost after that is...less expensive. So if @tonywei is planning on reusing the die later, and we are talking about 1,000+ quantities per run, then the time savings may be "bigly" enough to justify.